# How to tell if a database file exists in a codenameone app?

Tags: codenameone

I want to know whether a particular database file exists in my codenameone app.

Here's the code I have:

```
if (CN.existsInFileSystem(Display.getInstance()
                .getDatabasePath("my.db")))
        overwriteDb = false;
```

It seems that the `getDatabasePath` method will create the database if it doesn't already exist, at least on the windows/eclipse simulator. (I haven't tried on any devices).

The javadocs say that `getDatabasePath` will return `null` when the database doesn't exist, however it returns the path of the newly created db file.

Is there a way to get the path without actually creating a zero byte file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't create the database, I just verified it in the code. The JavaDoc is incorrect and I fixed it for the next update. The code you have should work just fine.

This is the Android implementation of the method:

```
public String getDatabasePath(String databaseName) {
    if (databaseName.startsWith("file://")) {
        return databaseName;
    }
    File db = new File(getContext().getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/" + databaseName);
    return db.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

You will notice null is never returned and nothing is created. The fixed docs look like this:

> Returns the file path of the Database if support for database exists on the platform.
>
> @param databaseName the name of the database with out / or path elements e.g. `mydatabase.db`
>
> @return the file path of the database or null if database isn't supported